# How to set up PATH during Nodist installation in Windows

Tags: node.js, path

During my installation of Nodist, the node version manager for Windows, I encountered an alert message that stated:

```
PATH not updated, original length 1030 > 1024
```

The result was that even Nodist was installed successfully(per installation feedback), entering 'nodist' at git bash at directory levels other than its resident directory (C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin) yielded:

```
'nodist' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

How can one set up PATH manually?

Answer (score 3):

Since nodist can be accessed from the directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin and not anywhere else, placing the path

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin
```

in the System Variables (accessible from Window's Advanced System Settings/Environmental Variables) corrects the problem. Many thanks to Marcel Klehr for the pointer.

Comment: When you have updated the path, close the console window and open a new one.

Comment: For those who use `chocolatey` there is no need to close console (or do log out in Windows), you may run `RefreshEnv` or `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\RefreshEnv.cmd`